# Help understanding the formation of band gap

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, electronic-band-theory

I need some help understanding how the energy band gap is formed. Here is my understanding so far:

1. Starting on the farthest right (largest interatomic spacing), the Si atoms are separate and thus their orbitals are not interacting. The 3p6/3s2 (largest outermost orbitals) thus all have the same energy level.
2. As the 3s/3p orbitals begin to overlap, the bands split due to the creation of bonding and antibonding orbitals. Since N is large, the many discrete levels formed are essentially close enough to regard as a continuous band.
3. As the interatomic spacing becomes even smaller, closer to the actual spacing of the crystal, the band-gap is formed.

Part 3 is where is lose my intuition. Why does there suddenly become an energy band with no allowed states? I do not see why there would be any bandgap formed, and instead I just imagine the top/bottom curves expanding out with a fully continuous region in between them. In other words, I can't see why the single continuous band (listed as 8N states, 4N electrons in the picture) would ever split into two bands with a bandgap in between.

Thank you very much for the help and let me know if I can further clarify my question.
[image]

Comment: How familiar are you with quantum mechanics?

Comment: Moderately so, if you can give an explanation I can fill in the details for myself. I have graduated with EE degree but am reviewing some old material I learned to try to fill in the gaps before grad school.

Comment: It is a nice picture to get the broad concepts across, but it should not be taken too literally. Connecting atomic orbitals to the full crystal band structure is not that simple.